# Create a Third Table With Laravel (eloquent)

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8, eloquent-relationship

I hope you can help me with this exercise.
I have to track the entry and exit of each person and display it in one row.

The models created so far are people and movements with the following relationships:
`Person-> hasMany (Movement :: class);`
`Movement-> belongsTo (Person :: class);`

Created the two tables and relations, now I have to create the third (person_movements). I am attaching the very descriptive scheme directly here

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e9sNN.jpg)

Thanks for your help

Comment: Hi I know your case I could explain how to do that here but you can follow this tutorial I have written on my website I believe it will help you. Here's the link https://webdevtrainee.com/laravel-9-eloquent-relationships/

Answer (score 0):

I would create a third table/model like below.

```php
class PersonMovement extends Model
{
    public function person()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'person_id');
    }

    public function entry()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'entry_id');
    }

    public function exit()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Person::class, 'exit_id');
    }
}
```

If you want to create/update the PersonMovement automatically you could listen to the created event:

```php
class Movement extends Model
{

...

public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        self::created(function($model){
            if (!$model->action === 'entry') {
                // create the PersonMovement
            } else {
                // update the latest PersonMovement
            }
        });
    }

...

}
```